# how to do pagination in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

hi i want to do pagination in my view page.can anyone tell me how to do that in vuejs..

Here is my view page:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <el-row :gutter="12">
        <el-col>
      <p>View Candidates</p>
    </el-col>
        </el-row>

    <el-row :gutter="12">
        <template v-for="c in candidates">
            <el-col :span="6">
            <Candidate :c="c" :key="c.id"></Candidate>
            </el-col>
        </template>
    </el-row>
</div>
```

here is my js page:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        candidates: window.data.candidates,
    }
},
components: { Candidate }
```

});

i am working on laravel5.4 and vuejs 2

Please can anyone help me..how to do this..

Comment: You'll need to tell us what window.data.candidates is. Do you just output data loaded in php as json_encode and set it as window variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real pagination you will need to ensure that your endpoints (from your post I'd say something like /candidates) will return json AND that it will return a pagniated object ofcourse.

In Laravel you'd do it like

```
public function index() {
   return Candidates::paginate(10);
}
```

EDIT: for more information regarding laravel pagination you can take a look at their examples and docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

A full example is rather hard to give but here a really short one

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('candidates', 'CandidateController@index');
```

**app/http/controller/CandidateController**

```
public function index() {
    $candidates = App\Candidate::paginate(10);

    return $candidates;
}
```

For a more detailed version of the laravel part you should provide your Controller, Migration, Routing setup.

In Vue I'd suggest you load all your data from within Vue and not with blade. Even though you could keep it as it is - it would be more "unified".

```
data: function() {
   return { paginator: null }
},
created: function() {
   // load initial first 10 entries
   axios.get('/candidates').then(function(response) {
      this.paginator = response.data;
   }.bind(this));
}
```

Ok so now you have the initial load as you had it before. You can loop through pagniator.data which is your actual list now. Small example:

```
<ul v-if="paginator"><!-- important !not loaded on initial render-->
   <li v-for="paginator.data as candidate">{{ candidate.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Now to the load more. Let's say you want a button for that. The paginator has a pro called **next_page_url** to give you the next http endpoint. If  it's null - now data is left to load.

```
<button v-if="paginator && paginator.next_page_url" @click.prevent="loadMore">Load more</button>
```

Button is setup - now the load more

```
methods: {
    loadMore: function() {
        // load next 10 elements
        axios.get(this.paginator.next_page_url).then(function(response) {
            // you have two options now. Either replace the paginator fully - then you will actually "page" your results. 
            // only 10 will be visible at any time
            this.paginator = response.data;
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

There you go this is an actual pagination. If you want to **loadMore** to add 10 elements to your current list it is a little bit more tricky because you don't want to replace the paginator.data with the new loaded stuff. You want to concat it.

```
...
axios.get(this.paginator.next_page_url).then(function(response) {
  response.data.data = this.paginator.data.concat(response.data.data);
  this.paginator = response.data;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: where we have to write this fucntion?public function index() {
   return Candidates::paginate(10);
}

Comment: This would be part of your Controller within laravel. I will enhance my question quickly and add more information.

Comment: i am just confusing where i have to add this code..i am new to vuejs..please explain me..

Comment: sadly I cannot give a full example because I can't tell if you have problems with vue or with laravel.

Comment: @FrankProvost Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363283/how-to-display-content-by-page-number-or-prev-next-clicked-on-the-vue